# Setting Default Value for Dynamic Dropdown Options in Angular FormProp

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following FormProp constant as:

```
const timeZoneProp = new FormProp<IdentityUserDto>({
    type: ePropType.Enum,
    name: 'TimeZoneId',
    displayName: '::TimeZone',
    isExtra: true,
    id: 'TimeZoneId',
    autocomplete: 'off',
    validators: () => [Validators.required],
    options: (data: PropData<IdentityUserDto>): Observable<Option<any>[]> => {
      const service = data.getInjected(TimeZoneService);
      return service
        .getList()
        .pipe(
          map(
            response =>
              response.items?.map(
                item =>
                  ({ key: item.description, value: item.id } as Option<any>)
              ) || []
          )
        );
    }
  });
```

This is working correctly; now I want to set a default value to that prop. This FormProp has a property: `defaultValue`:

```
readonly defaultValue: boolean | number | string | Date;
```

But the default value will not work because it needs data from the options prop. So I want the default value prop to be a promise of the code inside the options prop that got resolved under the constructor. So I try:

```
const timeZoneProp = new FormProp<IdentityUserDto>({
    type: ePropType.Enum,
    name: 'TimeZoneId',
    displayName: '::TimeZone',
    isExtra: true,
    id: 'TimeZoneId',
    autocomplete: 'off',
    defaultValue: new Promise(resolve => {
      const data = {}; 
      const optionsPromise = this.options(data).toPromise();

      optionsPromise.then(options => {
        if (options.length > 0) {
          resolve(options[0].value);
        } else {
          resolve(null); // Set default value to null if options array is empty
        }
      });
    }).then(
      resolvedValue =>
        resolvedValue as string | number | boolean | Date | undefined
    ), // Cast the resolved value to the appropriate type
    validators: () => [Validators.required],
    options: (data: PropData<IdentityUserDto>): Observable<Option<any>[]> => {
      const service = data.getInjected(TimeZoneService);
      return service
        .getList()
        .pipe(
          map(
            response =>
              response.items?.map(
                item =>
                  ({ key: item.description, value: item.id } as Option<any>)
              ) || []
          )
        );
    }
  });
```

But this throws an error in the defaultValue prop.

> Type 'Promise<string | number | boolean | Date | undefined>' is not
> assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date |
> undefined'.ts(2322) form-props.d.ts(36, 14): The expected type comes
> from property 'defaultValue' which is declared here on type '{
> validators?: PropCallback<IdentityUserDto, ValidatorFn[]> | undefined;
> asyncValidators?: PropCallback<IdentityUserDto, AsyncValidatorFn[]> |
> undefined; ... 15 more ...; name: string; }' (property) defaultValue?:
> string | number | boolean | Date | undefined

and the line `const optionsPromise = this.options(data).toPromise();` throw

```
this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

How can I achieve this?

Note: there are the docs for the [FormProp docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Dynamic-Form-Extensions#formpropoptions-r-any)